# AVCONV errors while grabbing af stream from an IPCAM

Tags: video, libav

When im trying to grab a stream from my D-Link DSC-932L Cam, using avconv, I keep getting errors.

Depending of framerate etc. the proces will terminate whitin a minute.

Here is the string and common error.

```
danker@BBHUSRA ~ $ avconv -f mjpeg  -v verbose -i "URL"/mjpeg.cgi -fflags discardcorrupt -y  /var/www/clips/IPCam.avi


avconv version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 14:52:53 with gcc 4.7.2
  configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  avutil      configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static
  avcodec     configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static
  avformat    configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static
  avdevice    configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static
  avfilter    configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static
  swscale     configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static
  postproc    configuration: --arch=i386 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil    51. 22. 1 / 51. 22. 1
  libavcodec   53. 35. 0 / 53. 35. 0
  libavformat  53. 21. 1 / 53. 21. 1
  libavdevice  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
  libavfilter   2. 15. 0 /  2. 15. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
[mjpeg @ 0x9142ae0] max_analyze_duration reached
[mjpeg @ 0x9142ae0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mjpeg, from '"URL"/mjpeg.cgi':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 320x240, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 1200k tbc
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj422p' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x9151aa0] w:320 h:240 pixfmt:yuvj422p
[avsink @ 0x928c260] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x9154dc0] w:320 h:240 fmt:yuvj422p -> w:320 h:240 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Output #0, avi, to '/var/www/clips/IPCam.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mpeg4)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
error count: 64= 26 q=6.7 size=    1589kB time=47.36 bitrate= 274.9kbits/s    
[mjpeg @ 0x914e5e0] error y=8 x=1
frame= 1188 fps= 26 q=6.2 Lsize=    1608kB time=47.52 bitrate= 277.2kbits/s    
video:1574kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.156245%
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem atm.. Stream is flickery in VLC but works just fine on Firefox.